# is there a way to zoom or maximize the images in rviz?

Tags: ros, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In rviz when you add an Image, a pane to the left appears and it shows the images a topic is publishing.
For example in the bottom left you can see the pane

[image: image description]

Is there a way to:

1. Maximize the image pane?
2. Zoom the image
3. Have some interactivity with the pane?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/370485/is-there-a-way-to-zoom-or-maximize-the-images-in-rviz?/) by [Kansai](https://answers.ros.org/users/54052/kansai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2021-01-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is there a way to:
>
> 1. Maximize the image pane?

not in the traditional sense of *maximising*. You can make it a floating window and then change the size, but it won't be docked in the main RViz windows any more.

> 1. Zoom the image

No.

> 1. Have some interactivity with the pane?

No.

Not with the default version of that display.

Perhaps there are some community contributed versions or alternatives, but I wouldn't know of any.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0